# How do you add custom help text to content entry/edit screens unrelated to field?

Tags: nodes

I use field groups to break my fields into "tabbed" areas for my content editors. I would like to be able to put some kind of help text at the beginning of each of those blocks to explain the entire section of entry. Each of the fields already have their own help text, this would be above all the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually do this with a `form_alter` myself in PHP code or I use the `help` entry for a Field.

Recently I found out about the [Markup](https://www.drupal.org/project/markup) module. I recommend you try it out. I have no added it to any of my projects yet, but it's on my todo list.

> This module adds the ability for site admins to add "Markup" widgets
>   to the form. These essentially let designers of cck content-types
>   insert additional markup into the node/edit form to display to
>   content-authors. This is the equivalent of adding additional elements
>   to $form of the type '#markup'.
>
> The module does not add anything to the $node object for the content
>   being created, and utilizes form_alter to remove unnecessary fields
>   from the '_content_admin_field' form when this widget is being
>   created.

Comment: When you do in code with form_alter, are you doing that in your theme files or is there somewhere else that can be more global to your site regardless of which theme you're using?

Comment: A custom module or theme.

Comment: OK, I'd rather use a contrib module if existing than do a custom one for this. I may give that a try.

Comment: Markup worked exactly as I had hoped!

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to create a block for each tabbed section. Then show the block based on the current path/url. Ensure that the block is enabled in the content top region, that way it will be displayed above your fields.

Answer (score 0):

The markup module is pretty easy to use and would do what you're looking for. https://www.drupal.org/project/markup

Other plus is that you can easily move it around on the page with no theming and you can still fine tune the look and feel with css if needed